# Show all data when a tooltip is triggered in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to show all data when hovering on specific data in Chart Js.

```js
let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d')
let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Data',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5],
      borderColor: 'blue'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        mode: 'nearest',
        callbacks: {
          label: function (tooltipItem) {
            console.log([[tooltipItem.label, tooltipItem.raw]]);
            return tooltipItem.raw;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

});
```

```css
.as-console-row-code {
  white-space: initial !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Is there a way to print this below output when a tooltip is triggered?

```js
[['January',12], ['February',19], ['March',3], ['April',5]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the mode: 'dataset' in tooltip config:

```js
let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d')
let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Data',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5],
      borderColor: 'blue'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        mode: 'dataset',
        callbacks: {
          label: function (tooltipItem) {
            return [tooltipItem.label, tooltipItem.raw].toString();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.as-console-row-code {
  white-space: initial !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the label callback function of the tooltip plugin, you can access the chart object and get the labels and data for each tooltip item using the getDatasetMeta and data methods.

```js
let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Data',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5],
      borderColor: 'blue'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        mode: 'nearest',
        callbacks: {
          label: function (tooltipItem, chart) {
            let datasetIndex = tooltipItem.datasetIndex;
            let dataIndex = tooltipItem.index;
            let label = chart.data.labels[dataIndex];
            let value = chart.data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[dataIndex];
            console.log([[label, value]]);
            return value;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.as-console-row-code {
  white-space: initial !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```